# jQuery question adding more than one dropable textbox

Tags: jquery

http://jsfiddle.net/5DCZw/2/ i found this fiddle on the website here, and I cant figure out how to add multiple textboxes that would also be dropable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple. Simply add more selectors to your `.droppable()` line:

```
$(function() {
    $(".draggable").draggable({
        revert: true,
        helper: 'clone',
        start: function(event, ui) {
            $(this).fadeTo('fast', 0.5);
        },
        stop: function(event, ui) {
            $(this).fadeTo(0, 1);
        }
    });

    $("#droppable, #droppable2").droppable({    // ***
        hoverClass: 'active',
        drop: function(event, ui) {
            this.value = $(ui.draggable).text();
        }
    });
});
```

Example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jamwaffles/JmBUs/). I'd recommend adding a class if you're using a bunch of inputs, as using `$(this)` will only point to the current object (input).

Answer (score 1):

Or with a class:

```
<input type="text" id="droppable1" class="droppable" />
<input type="text" id="droppable2" class="droppable" />
<input type="text" id="droppable3" class="droppable" />
```

...

```
$(".droppable").droppable({
    hoverClass: 'active',
    drop: function(event, ui) {
        this.value = $(ui.draggable).text();
    }
});
```

so you can also style all of them using css

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#droppable2").droppable({
    hoverClass: 'active',
    drop: function(event, ui) {
        this.value = $(ui.draggable).text();
    }
});
$("#droppable3").droppable({
    hoverClass: 'active',
    drop: function(event, ui) {
        this.value = $(ui.draggable).text();
    }
});
$("#droppable4").droppable({
    hoverClass: 'active',
    drop: function(event, ui) {
        this.value = $(ui.draggable).text();
    }
});
```

and so on...

http://jsfiddle.net/5DCZw/144/